# Describe a 2-D surface by the total/average/maximum amount of curvature

Tags: differential-geometry

I want to describe a function by the amount of curvature or variability it has. For example the surface

$f(x,y) = \sin(4 \pi x) \cos \left(\frac{7 \pi}{2} y \right)$

has more variability than

$g(x,y) = \sin(\pi x) \cos \left(\frac{\pi}{2} y \right)$

on the same region because $f(x,y)$ has a greater frequency. I would like to quantify this amount of variability for these functions and others $\left(h(x,y) = x^2 y^2 \right.$, or $\left. j(x,y) = \exp(x) \exp(y) \right)$.

**EDIT** Motivation: I'm modeling an analytic solution that gives me errors that reach machine precision if the analytic solution isn't "curvy" (varying) enough (i.e., my model does too good of a job on functions that are too invariant, which isn't helpful). So I'd like a quantifiable way to describe the curvature of the [analytic] function.

Comment: Welcome to Math.SE! In order to help potential answerers, could you please add to your question something about your motivation? Qualitative, open-ended conditions without any indication of underlying aims are [too unfocused for this site](http://math.stackexchange.com/tour), and unlikely to garner responses that are useful to you.

Answer (score 1):

In Dynamics, time rate of change of acceleration is at times referred to as jerk. I do not know about corresponding name of  rate of change of  curvature or its next derivative with spatial independent variable. In mechanics of beams these are proportional to shear forces and rate of load but still no name is given / known to me.

In surface theory you can perhaps, if needed device your own suitable differential definition like  $ dH/dl $ on average curvature for a specific direction $l$ or $ dK/dA $ as Gauss curvature change per unit area defined by chosen parameters.

EDIT1:

If K alone is required for Monge form $z=f(x,y)$

$$ \frac{rt-s^2}{(1+p^2+q^2)^2} $$

It is in terms of partial derivatives. Higher the $K$ or higher the double curvature more is the deviation from flatness.